# Multisite- different localizations and domains but same codebase and user base

Tags: multi-sites

I have an established site which caters to Australian market and now I want to launch a similar site for US market.

- New site will have a different domain
- New site will have different content

However, I want both sites to share code and users so that someone who has an account on Australian site should be able to log in to US site plus any changes in code should reflect on both sites.

Sorry I am bit a knoob and will appreciate some guidance.

Comment: I have a dedicated server - Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have lots of fun with this one if you're a "knoob".

The module you want to look at is [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain). This will do pretty much exactly what you want to do. It's a slightly heavy configuration so if you are new, then you might struggle but you can probably get some assistance on #drupal-support on freenode.